# Add page to asp.net website if source code/project solution is not available

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-webpages

I have been working on my clients site.

My client has only `aspx` and `dll` files now I want to add a new page to website, for testing purpose I have created a new project and uploaded its `dll` and `aspx` file but when I run the page it says.

> Could not load type 'abc.index1122'

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="index1122.aspx.cs" Inherits="abc.index1122" %>
```

Comment: You should be able to add an ASPX file and the corresponding code behind ASPX.CS file (ie. source code not compiled DLL) and it should work but won't be able to access any classes from the existing site.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the uncompiled solution from your client. Start with that first.

If that code is not available, you have the more difficult road of grabbing a decompiler (I recommend Telerik's JustDecompile), and then reverse engineer a solution out of the DLLs. Only then can you start making additions and recompile / deploy the code to the target machine.

Comment: any easy solution
Coz the uncompiled version is not avilable

Comment: Negative. You're effectively asking "How can I add some code to an EXE without the uncompiled solution". You're going to have to reverse engineer the code to start making additions.